# Python (on databricks) how to process csv data returned as bytes

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, databricks

I have some python code which calls an API.  This API returns data as "CSV" but it doesnt deliver a file,it returns "bytes".  for example, if I do:

```
print(result)
```

it returns:

```
b'"column1"| "column2"/n"value1"|"value2"/n"anothervaluesecondrow"|"secondvaluesecondrow"/n'
```

my goal is to parse and write this to a databricks table.  I can decode this into a string like

```
decoded=result.decode()
```

Maybe my brain is not functioning at 100% capacity today, but for the life of my I can't figure how to read this in.  For example, if I do something like this:

```
sparkdf=spark.read.option("header", True).option("inferSchema", True).option("sep", "|").csv(decoded)
```

I get an error like:

```
IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: <followed by the first lines of data>
```

because it's expecting a path to the data, not the data itself.

I'm sure I've done this before, but for the life of me can't remember what I'm doing wrong.  Appreciate any help!

Comment: Well, I am able to get the results in by doing:


`
result=getQueryResult(sessionId,jobid).decode().  
pandasdf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(result), sep='|',dtype='unicode').  
sparkDF=spark.createDataFrame(pandasdf) 
table=f"{internaldb}.mytablename"
sparkDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(table) 
`
but when I select form that table I get an error like "Error in SQL statement: IllegalStateException: Couldn't find columname#2160 in somecolume#1234, somothercolumn#8765

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  First I created a function to change any columns which have a "NullType()" data type to string, then I was able to first import the data as pandas df, convert to spark df, redefine the null columns and write to a table:

```
def removeVoidColumnsFromSparkDF(df):
    new_fields = []
    for field in df.schema:
        new_data_type = StringType() if str(field.dataType) == "NullType()" else field.dataType
        new_fields.append(StructField(field.name, new_data_type, field.nullable))
    new_schema = StructType(new_fields)
    return spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, new_schema)

pandasdf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(result), sep='|',dtype='unicode')
sparkDF=spark.createDataFrame(pandasdf) 
table=f"{internaldb}.mytable"
new_df = removeVoidColumnsFromSparkDF(sparkDF)
new_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(table)
```